# Can elasticsearch do a running tally of a number field?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

If I have a facet like

```
  "histogram": {
    "key_field": "timestamp",
    "value_field": "amount",
    "time_interval": "1d"
  }
```

I get a result set back like

```
{
  key: 1222732800000
  count: 642
  min: -985
  max: 483.25
  total: 1544.4000024795532
  total_count: 642
  mean: 2.4056074804977463
}
```

Is there a way that I can get peak high and peak low of the tally?  In other words if amount was a number series like:

```
-4, -8, 10, -3, 30, -20
```

What i need is a way to determine that the tally's peak low was -12 and its peak high was 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, elasticsearch doesn't support this operation.